# Не запускается бот через командную строку

Tags: python, aiogram

Всё верно, ошибок в коде не имеется, но строка тупо не хочет запускать бот, пишу бот.пай, команда обрабатывается и сразу же прерывается.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXvyE.png

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Мне нужно понять, почему не запускается бот, сделанный на бибилеотеке aiogram, командная строка не запускает бота, хотя в коде не выдает ошибку.

Comment: тебе нужно использовать использовать команду запуска интерпритатора а не просто указывать файл. python bot.py

Answer (score 0):

Используй команду запуска скриптов на python в терминале.

```
python bot.py
```

либо

```
python3 bot.py
```